# error running run file in centOS - bad display

Tags: linux, oracle, centos

I have a task to install Oracle 11g on a centOS 8 using VM (i'm new to linux / oracle).
I downloaded the Oracle files and unzipped them, then I tried to ./runInstaller but I get an error and this is the full terminal with error:

```
login as: admin
admin@192.168.163.129's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

Last login: Thu May 21 09:26:48 2020 from 192.168.163.1
[admin@oracledb ~]$ cd Downloads
[admin@oracledb Downloads]$ cd database
[admin@oracledb database]$ ls
doc      linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2  response  runInstaller  stage
install  linux.x64_11gR2_database_2of2  rpm       sshsetup      welcome.html
[admin@oracledb database]$ ./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 120 MB.   Actual 2027 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 1759 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
    >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n] y


>>> Ignoring required pre-requisite failures. Continuing...
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2020-05-21_09-43-58AM. Please wait ...
DISPLAY not set. Please set the DISPLAY and try again.
Depending on the Unix Shell, you can use one of the following commands as examples to set the DISPLAY environment variable:
- For csh:                      % setenv DISPLAY 192.168.1.128:0.0
- For sh, ksh and bash:         $ DISPLAY=192.168.1.128:0.0; export DISPLAY
Use the following command to see what shell is being used:
        echo $SHELL
Use the following command to view the current DISPLAY environment variable setting:
        echo $DISPLAY
- Make sure that client users are authorized to connect to the X Server.
To enable client users to access the X Server, open an xterm, dtterm or xconsole as the user that started the session and type the following command:
% xhost +
To test that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly, run a X11 based program that comes with the native operating system such as 'xclock':
        % <full path to xclock.. see below>
If you are not able to run xclock successfully, please refer to your PC-X Server or OS vendor for further assistance.
Typical path for xclock: /usr/X11R6/bin/xclock
[admin@oracledb database]$
```

I am using putty and Xming but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your putty session is connecting with "x-11 port forwarding"

[image: Putty X11 configuration]

Be sure after you set this that you scroll back up to 'Session' and then 'save'

Comment: Go back and double check that your putty session settings got saved.  Putty is quirky about that.  Also I notice that you are trying to install an old and unsupported version of Oracle on an OS (CentOS) that it was never certified for.  Even if you allow for the fact that CentOS is in the same family of LInux as is Oracle and Red Hat (for which oracle _is_ certified), you have gone a bridge too far on the version, as oracle 11g is only certified to Oracle/RedHat v 7.

Comment: Yes X11 is still enabled and error occurs :< . To be honest, I just got this task to install oracle g11 on CentOS as a task in my job interview. I see all videos in youtube people  use a user named "oracle" and then they are able to run the installer, but they do not explain when/how they created this user and what priviliges it has. hope to get further assistance :3

Comment: I hate to sound harsh, but if a job interview expects you to be able to complete a certain task, and you don't even know the most fundamental parts ("they do not explain when/how they created this user") and you are relying on specious youtube videos instead of the actual documentation (docs.oracle.com) then how do you expect to handle the job?  And have you considered that what they were really looking for might be to see if you have the knowledge and conviction to push back against installing unsupported software ....

Comment: Checking Temp space: must be greater than 120 MB.   Actual 8157 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 1490 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 16777216    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2020-05-23_06-14-24AM. Please wait ...[oracle@localhost database]$ There was an error trying to initialize the HPI library.
Please check your installation, HotSpot does not work correctly
when installed in the JDK 1.2 Linux Production Release, or
with any JDK 1.1.x release